# YouTube Videos with False Titles

Tags: halacha, internet, sheker-false

Would Halacha consider making YouTube videos and putting false titles, with lies, and making money off of the videos, stealing or lying? For example, if you make a video, “How to Get a Free iPhone” and in the video you show a fake method. Does Halacha consider this a sin? Thanks!

Comment: Regardless of whether it's a sin or not, I certainly hope you're not planning to do this.

Comment: אינו עוסק בישובו של עולם

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are "clickbait" links permissible?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67192/are-clickbait-links-permissible)

Answer (score 6):

First, please read my answer on ["are internet clickbait links permissible](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67192/are-clickbait-links-permissible).

Your case is much worse because of two factors:

- The author surely knows it is a lie and has an evil intention to fool people.
- People can only lose (time, effort) from this information, never profit (unlike clickbaits that a small portion of people does enjoy).

Therefore posting false videos on Youtube, as any false information falls under two prohibitions ([Leviticus.25](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.25?vhe=Tanach_with_Text_Only&lang=bi&aliyot=0)):

> 1. "ולא תונו איש את־עמיתו ויראת מאלהיך כי אני ה' אלקיכם"
>
> Do not wrong one another, but fear your God; for I the LORD am your God.

And 2. "גניבת דעת" (deception and stealing one's attention/effort)

THere's also a possibility of transgressing "ולפני עוור לא תתן מכשול" ([ibid 19) as Rashi puts it](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Leviticus.19.14.2?vhe=Pentateuch_with_Rashi%27s_commentary_by_M._Rosenbaum_and_A.M._Silbermann_--_corrected_vocalization&lang=bi):

> "**ולפני עור לא תתן מכשול**. לִפְנֵי הַסּוּמָא בְדָבָר לֹא תִתֵּן עֵצָה שֶׁאֵינָהּ הוֹגֶנֶת לוֹ, אַל תֹּאמַר מְכֹר שָׂדְךָ וְקַח לְךָ חֲמוֹר, וְאַתָּה עוֹקֵף עָלָיו וְנוֹטְלָהּ הֵימֶנּוּ (שם):
>
> THOU SHALT NOT PUT A STUMBLING BLOCK BEFORE THE BLIND — This implies: "Give not a person who is "blind" in a matter an advice which is improper for him. Do not say to him: "Sell your field and buy from the proceeds of the sale an ass", the fact being that you are endeavouring to circumvent him and to take it (the field) from him (Sifra, Kedoshim, Section 2 14).

Comment: Look [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.20.13?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Sforno_on_Exodus.20.13.2&lang2=bi) at what Sforno says, dibbur hamaschil "lo tignov"